# Remove a JFrame from taskbar in Java

Tags: java, taskbar

I did a quick topic look, but did not find something similar.

My query is: how can I prevent a child window appearing on the Windows taskbar when it is shown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a JDialog instead of a JFrame

Comment: I want to show it on taskbar but hide it when it's minimized to tray icon.

Answer (score 16):

JDK 1.7 brings you method setType. Use following method.

```
JFrame.setType(javax.swing.JFrame.Type.UTILITY)
```

Comment: Type.UTILITY didn't work for me, but Type.POPUP did.